# Create a static menu CSS

Tags: html, css, wordpress, web

Is there a way to set a menu in a Wordpress DIVI site as static?

```
#main-header {
    position: fixed !important;
}
```

For instance, like [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight).

The menu stays on the top and as you scroll down, you no longer see it. So it does not go as a sticky menu. Please share your thoughts!

Cheers,

Just a regular dude

Comment: Which menu are you talking about on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight?

Comment: position: ralative

Comment: @pol close one. You meant `position: relative;` Though context and explanation would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the Divi theme, the easiest solution is to just set it in the themes settings. Divi -> General -> Fixed Navigation bar, and then turn it off. Look at the attached screenshot: 
https://www.screencast.com/t/VZyvBc3Am
BTW, putting the position to fixed will make the menu always stay in the same position in your browser, so it will do the exact opposite of what you want. Let me know if this helped

Comment: Thank you Kind Sir! You shall have my eternal gratitude! Have yourself a harmonious Monday!

Comment: Glad I helped! If you want to make my Monday even better, please choose my answer as the accepted answer to your question, there should be a checkmark on the left :)